# dc.js - How to use .cap() with .valueAccessor()?

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js

Drawing charts with dc.js library, i need to use **.cap()** method in a piechart using **.valueAccessor()**.

The same chart:

- **Without .cap() :** it is drawn perfectly ordered correctly on the .valueAccessor()
- **With .cap() :** the chart is drawn without errors in the js console, but it doesn't show the right result, it seems that it orders by value and not by valueAccessor.

This is an example to explain better:

```js
var chartProblems = dc.pieChart('#chart');
var chartProblems1 = dc.pieChart('#chart1');



var data = [{
  Ticket: 0,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 1,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 1,
  Problem: 'bb'
}, {
  Ticket: 1,
  Problem: 'cc'
}, {
  Ticket: 2,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 3,
  Problem: 'bb'
}, {
  Ticket: 3,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 4,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 5,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 6,
  Problem: 'zzz'
}, {
  Ticket: 6,
  Problem: 'bb'
}, {
  Ticket: 7,
  Problem: 'bb'
}, {
  Ticket: 8,
  Problem: 'dd'
}, {
  Ticket: 9,
  Problem: 'ee'
}, {
  Ticket: 9,
  Problem: 'ff'
}, {
  Ticket: 10,
  Problem: 'cc'
}, ];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
ProblemsDimension = ndx.dimension(function(b) {
  return b.Problem
});
ProblemGroup = ProblemsDimension.group()
  .reduce(
    function(p, d) {

      if (d.Ticket in p.Ticket) p.Ticket[d.Ticket] ++;
      else {
        p.Ticket[d.Ticket] = 1;
        p.TicketCount++;
      }
      return p;
    },

    function(p, d) {
      p.Ticket[d.Ticket] --;
      if (p.Ticket[d.Ticket] === 0) {
        delete p.Ticket[d.Ticket];
        p.TicketCount--;
      }
      return p;
    },

    function() {
      return {
        TicketCount: 0,
        Ticket: {}
      };
    }
  );


chartProblems
  .width(300)
  .height(300)
  //.margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
  .dimension(ProblemsDimension)

.group(ProblemGroup)

.colors(d3.scale.category20())
  // assign colors to each value in the x scale domain
  //.ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
  .label(function(d) {
    return d.key + ': ' + d.value.TicketCount;
  })
  // title sets the row text
  .title(function(d) {
    return d.key + ': ' + d.value.TicketCount;
  })

//.elasticX(true)
//.xAxis().ticks(4)
;
chartProblems
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
    return d.value.TicketCount;
  })
  .ordering(function(b) {
    return -b.value.TicketCount
  })
  .cap(2);
chartProblems.render();

chartProblems1
  .width(300)
  .height(300)
  //.margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
  .dimension(ProblemsDimension)

.group(ProblemGroup)

.colors(d3.scale.category20())
  // assign colors to each value in the x scale domain
  //.ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
  .label(function(d) {
    return d.key + ': ' + d.value.TicketCount;
  })
  // title sets the row text
  .title(function(d) {
    return d.key + ': ' + d.value.TicketCount;
  })

//.elasticX(true)
//.xAxis().ticks(4)
;
chartProblems1
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
    return d.value.TicketCount;
  })
  .ordering(function(b) {
    return -b.value.TicketCount
  })
  //.cap(2)
;
chartProblems1.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://tvinci.github.io/webs/js/d3.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://tvinci.github.io/webs/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>With cap
        <br/>
        <div id="chart"></div>
      </td>
      <td>Same chart without cap
        <br/>
        <div id="chart1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Also here: [http://jsfiddle.net/atagliavini/LypsLtot](http://jsfiddle.net/atagliavini/LypsLtot/)/

How can i solve this problem?
Have i forgot something?

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late but here's how I solved the problem.I created a custom `othersGrouper` and `cappedValueAccessor` function of the chart.Below is the code for the same.

```
chartProblems.othersGrouper(function (topItems, restItems) {
            var restItemsSum = d3.sum(restItems, chartProblems.valueAccessor()),
                restKeys = restItems.map(chartProblems.keyAccessor());
            if (restItemsSum > 0) {
                topItems = topItems.concat([{
                    others: restKeys,
                    key: chartProblems.othersLabel(),
                    // value:restItemsSum,
                    value: {
                        TicketCount: restItemsSum

                    }
                }]);
            }
            return topItems;
        });     
chartProblems.cappedValueAccessor = function (d, i) {
            if (d.others) {
                return d.value.TicketCount;
            }
            return chartProblems.valueAccessor()(d, i);
        };
```

since you have reduced your group to return a custom object , you have to modify the othersgrouper and cappedvalueAccessor function in order to use the `cap` functionality of the pie chart.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lwn73L5/1/) is the updated link of the fiddle used above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I fixed your problem. I replaced `.cap( )` with `.data( )` and ordered the data according to **TicketCount** and pre-filtered the data to be rendered. Now you would get only those **top(n)** Key-value pairs those you mention within `.data( )`.
Modified code:

```
.data(function (ProblemGroup) {
return ProblemGroup.order(function(p) {
    return p.TicketCount;
}).top(2);
})
```

This is the [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/2Lwn73L5/) with specified chages.

> .data([callback])
>
> Set the data callback or retrieve the chart's data set. The data
>   callback is passed the chart's group and by default will return
>   group.all(). This behavior may be modified to, for instance, return
>   only the top 5 groups:
>
> ```
> chart.data(function(group) {
>     return group.top(5);
> });
> ```

Comment: your solution is not good for me because i need to see the "Other" slice of the pieChart.